# Graphql_flutter runMutation's QueryResult is returning null, though the mutation is executing correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, graphql-mutation, flutter-graphql

I'm using graphql_flutter 3.1.0 and have started the authentication for my app and am needing to set the user in my Provider state on successful creation. My mutation to CreateUser is currently:

```
final String createUserMutation = """
mutation CreateUser(\$firstName: String!, \$username: String!, \$phoneNumber: String!) {
  CreateUser(firstName: \$firstName, username: \$username, phoneNumber: \$phoneNumber, role: USER) {
    id,
    firstName,
    username,
    phoneNumber,
    role
  }
}
""";
```

This successfully creates the user in my Neo4j database. If I run that same query in my GraphQL interface, I get the response exactly as expected:

```
{
  "data": {
    "CreateUser": {
      "id": "e2a44525-fd46-4aae-8e00-38d263b769e6",
      "firstName": "Sam",
      "username": "sgamgee",
      "phoneNumber": "3216543216",
      "role": "USER"
    }
  }
}
```

In my `SignupForm` widget I am wrapping the form in `Mutation` and passing the `createUserMutation` to the `MutationOptions` like so:

```
class SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final user = User();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
      child: Mutation(
        options: MutationOptions(
          documentNode: gql(createUserMutation)
        ),
        builder: (RunMutation runMutation, QueryResult result) {
          return UserCreateForm(
            formKey: _formKey, 
            user: user,
            runMutation: runMutation,
            result: result
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

All is well so far, no errors. When I attempt to submit the form via an onPressed closure:

```
onPressed: () async {
  final form = _formKey.currentState;
  if (form.validate()) {
    form.save();
                    
    runMutation({
      'firstName': user.firstName,
      'username': user.username,
      'phoneNumber': user.phoneNumber
    });
                    
    if (result.hasException) {
      return AlertBox(
        type: AlertType.error,
        text: result.exception.toString()
      );
    } else if (result.loading) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      // NOTE: result.data is null though the mutation is running successfully. 
      var createdUser = result.data['CreateUser'];
      Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).signUp(createdUser);
                      
      if (Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated()) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signup-success');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signup');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result.data is consistently null. I know neither `runMutation` or `result` are futures and thus cannot be awaited. Also `hasException` and `loading` are present and false or true as the case may be. Does anyone notice anything else going on that could cause `result.data` to consistently be null?